# WordPress Looping through products

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

Have a wordpress site with woocommerce.

I'm trying to add descriptions for the categories.

It is only adding a description for the first category and then copies it to the other categories.

In my child-themes functions.php I added:

```
function add_descript() {
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        exit; // Exit if accessed directly
    }

    global $post;

        if ( ! $post->post_excerpt ) {
            return;
        }

?>
<div itemprop="description">
    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ) ?>
</div> <?php 
}



add_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', 'add_descript' );
```

Is there a way to loop through all of the categories and grab and excerpt?

Thanks,
Matt